# Eclipse error with Phalcon

Tags: php, eclipse, phalcon, eclipse-pdt

In the `app/controllers/ArticleController.php` file I wrote this :

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
   ...
}
```

I created the file with another editor ( PHPDesigner ) and everything was ok , but when I opened the file with Eclipse then I got errors :

```
Parser error "';' expected after expression (Found token: Identifier(Phalcon))" ArticleController.php   /resto/app/controllers  line 3  PHP Problem
```

So how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Change php interpreter version (global or on project) into 5.3 or above (Preferences -> PHP -> interpreter, or Project->properties->php->interpreter)